# How do I configure "ulimits" for a Docker container running in AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

My Java application appears to be running out of "open files" limit when running in a Docker container in AWS ECS. Upon further investigation, I found that the open files limit defaults to 1024.

Typically, in Linux I would edit `/etc/security/limits.conf`. That does not appear to take effect when I modify that file in my Docker container.

I know I can also pass command line ulimit parameters to `docker run` as documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container-ulimit). But I do not have direct access to the Docker command line in ECS. There's gotta be a way to do it via a Task definition. How do I accomplish this ?

Comment: Upon further investigation, I found an approach for configuring ulimits in ECS task definitions and documented it in [my blog post](http://www.computerworld.com/article/3067303/cloud-computing/how-to-configuring-linux-usage-limits-with-docker-and-aws-ecs.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ECS task definition JSON allows you to set ulimits.
The Ulimits on ecs task definition correspond to Ulimits in docker run.

Please refer to the following page for more information:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

Via the Console navigate to the task definitions and under the "Resource Limits" section you can set the NOFILE soft/hard limits

[image]

For cloudformation you can set it via the task definition > Container Definition > Ulimits
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinition-ulimits

Be mindful of the fact that you should keep the hard limit below 1/10th of the afforded memory in Kilobytes to this task.